# Text Input Selection not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, selection

I am trying to get the user selected text in a text input when a button is clicked. This what I am trying:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedText () {
            if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
                var range = window.getSelection ();                                        
                alert (range.toString ());
            } 
            else {
                if (document.selection.createRange) { // Internet Explorer
document.getElementById("foo").focus();
                    var range = document.selection.createRange();
                    alert (range.text);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="GetSelectedText ()">Get the selected text!</button>
    <input type = 'text' id = 'foo' />12345
</body>
```

It works as expected in all browsers, except `IE9`. In `IE9`, if you select some text from the `12345` chunk and press the button, the selected text is alerted all right. However, if you type something in the text input, select some of it, and click the button, a blank alert is generated.

Can anyone tell me how do I get it working in `IE9`? And is there any way to get the cursor position of the selection start as well (something like Mozilla's `selectionStart`)? Iam looking for Javascript solution, without `Rangy` or other related jQuery libraries..

Comment: Actually your code won't work in Firefox either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text inputs and textareas have a separate selection API, namely `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the input itself. These are not supported in IE <= 8, but you already have the alternative for those.

Here's an implementation of your `GetSelectedText()` function that works in all major browsers:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UK8gA/

Code:

```
function GetSelectedText() {
    var selectedText = "";
    var input = document.getElementById("foo");
    var sel, val = input.value;
    input.focus();
    if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number") {
        selectedText = val.slice(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd);
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.createRange) { // IE
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = range.text;
    }
    alert(selectedText);
}
```

Comment: Well, what did you do differently? You are also using `document.selection.createRange()` and then `range.text` to get the text..

Comment: Never mind, got it. Can you tell me whether there is any way to get the starting cursor position as well? (I think there is, `Rangy` does it, after all!)

Comment: @Cupidvogel: `selectionStart` is what you need. The workaround for  old IE is a bit tricky with line breaks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373056/96100 is one example.

Comment: Hi Tim, have you observed one thing, that if you replace the button by say a `p`, and attach the clickhandler to it, only a blank pop up is alerted in IE9?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Yes. This happens in all versions of IE because the selection is destroyed by the time the `click` event fires. You can get round this by making the element being clicked unselectable (using `unselectable="on"` in IE) or by handling the `mousedown` event instead.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: I think buttons just behave differently. If a user clicks on a button, it is unlikely that they intended to start making a selection. If the user instead clicks on a piece of regular content, they could be trying to deselect the current selection, or be initiating a new selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the jQuery Caret plugin: [jCaret](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php)

```
// Get start pos in intput box with id="box1"
$("#box1").caret().start

// Get end pos
$("#box1").caret().end

// Get selected text
$("#box1").caret().text
```

Comment: Yeah I know there are jQuery solutions like `Rangy` or this one. I am looking for a strictly Javascript implementation...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you then.

Answer (score 0):

It all looks good except that the line "document.getElementById("foo").focus();" does not appear to be necessary and is probably why the browser is unable to detect the highlighted text. Try to remove it and see what you get.

Comment: I added it later to see whether it works. It didn't work without that too..:)